# Cucumber-js 3.x: how get scenario name in Before hook?

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

I use Cucumber 3.x and I want get scenario name in Before hook. My code seems like this:

```
Before(function (scenario) {
        let name = scenario.name;
         console.log(scenario) //debug printing

        return require("./driver").createDriver(desired);
    });
```

And console.log in Cucumber 3.x shows only this:

```
{ sourceLocation:
   { uri: 'name_my_feature.feature',
     line: 206 } } //206 - is line current scenario name
```

How I can get scenario name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it under `scenario.pickle.name`